# Django add comment section on posts feed

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to share a project that currently can create user and each user can create N posts 
The source is available on [github](https://github.com/Guillermonv/DjangoPosts/)

and I has two models users and post 
[image]

and the template layers

[image]

Currently the feed for each post has a button that send an commenting the post I want to change that to put the comments of the post and not send and email each user should be able to comment a post and the comment should remain

```
{% block container %}
<body id="bg" img style="zoom: 85%; background-position: center center; background-attachment: fixed;background-repeat:no-repeat;padding:5px; background-image: url('{% static "/back.png"%}') ";>
<div style="background-image: url({% static 'static/img/back.png' %});">

    <div class="row" style="align:center">
        {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 offset-md-4 mt-5 p-0 post-container,width:50%;">
            <div class="card" style="width: 32rem;width:50%;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="media pt-3 pl-3 pb-1">
                        <a href="{% url " users:detail" post.user.username%}">
                        <img alt="{{ post.user.username }}" class="mr-3 rounded-circle" height="35"
                             src="{{ post.profile.picture.url }}">
                        </a>
                        <h3 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h3>
                    </div>

                    <p class="card-text">{{ post.desc }}</p>

                </div>
            </div>
            <img alt="{{ post.title }}" src="{{ post.photo.url }}" style="width: 50%; heigth:60%">

            <div class="media-body">
                <b><p style="margin-top: 5px;">@{{ post.user.username }} - <small>{{ post.created }}</small>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a href="" style="color: #000; font-size: 20px;">
                        <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
                    </a>
                    <br>
                </p></b>


            </div>
            <!-- COMENT SECTION THAT I WANT TO IMPLEMENT MY FEATURE-->
            <form action="{% url 'posts:comment_new' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}

                <input
                        class="form-control {% if form.title.errors %}is-invalid{% endif %}"
                        name="title"
                        size="16"
                        type="hidden"
                        value="{{post.title}}"
                >

                <input
                        class="form-control {% if form.title.errors %}is-invalid{% endif %}"
                        name="first_name "
                        size="16"
                        type="hidden"
                        value="{{user.first_name}}"
                >
                <input
                        class="form-control {% if form.title.errors %}is-invalid{% endif %}"
                        name="last_name "
                        size="16"
                        type="hidden"
                        value="{{user.last_name}}"
                >
                <textarea class="form-control" cols="50" name="comment" rows="5"
                          style="width:50%;" value="{{ comments.comment }}"></textarea>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info btn-lg" style="width:35%; display:block;margin:auto;" type="submit">
                    Publish
                </button>

            </form>
        </div>
        <br>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

As I said I want to replace this form function call to create a comment section instead sending a email with the comment

```
< form action = "{% url 'posts:comment_new' %}">


def comment_new(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = request.POST['comment']
        subject = request.POST['title']
        user = request.POST['first_name']
        last_name = request.POST['last_name']
        # lastname = request.POST['lastname']

        send_mail("[MAIL] " + subject, user + " " + last_name + " said  " + message + " on http://url.com:8000",
                  'guillermo.varelli@gmail.com',
                  ['guillermo.varelli@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created')
    return render(request, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates', 'posts', 'feed.html'), {'posts': posts})
```

I think this maybe create a comment with user and post id with the comment detail

```
def comment_new(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':   
        message = request.POST['comment']
        subject = request.POST['title']
        user = request.POST['first_name']
        last_name = request.POST['last_name']

        #lastname = request.POST['lastname']
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form.save()
```

***One options its create a comment***

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    """
    #id= models.AutoField(max_length=1000, blank=True)

    # post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='',on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=0)
    """

    #comment = models.ForeignKey('posts.Post', related_name='posts_rel', to_field="comments", db_column="comments",
     #                           on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=1, blank=True)
    post = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True,unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    username = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True ,max_length=200)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
```

and then the form

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        """form settings"""
        model = Comment
        fields = ('user','username','post','comment',)
```

**finally with the function I'm able to persist but not able to render**

```
form = CommentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

#     print formset.errors

```
if form.is_valid():
   form.save()
```

but I can't find the way to render the object on the html file

```
please feel free to suggest any solution or better create a pull request on the public git hub repo
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? so instead of calling ```sendmail()``` you should create a comment... validate the post data and then call somewhere ```Comment.objects.create()``` it would be easier though to use a ```ModelForm``` and display it on the template. this way you dont need to manualy render each field and can easily validate/create a new comment.

Comment: i tried to create a comment model but was unable to create and render  through  a function due to the relation post user
class Comment(models.Model): <br>

    post = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True,unique=True,default=0) <br>
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=0,null=True)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the book [Django 2 by Example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1788472489) we can find a step by step guide to **create a comment system**, wherein the users will be able to comment on posts.

In order to do it, is as simple as the following four steps

1. Create a model to save the comments
2. Create a form to submit comments and validate the input data
3. Add a view that processes the form and saves the new comment to the database
4. Edit the post detail template to display the list of comments and the form to add a new comment

---

> 1. Create a model to save the comments

In your models.py file for the application, add the following code

```
class Comment(models.Model): 
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80) 
    email = models.EmailField() 
    body = models.TextField() 
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) 
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True) 

    class Meta: 
        ordering = ('created',) 

    def __str__(self): 
        return 'Comment by {} on {}'.format(self.name, self.post)
```

The new Comment model you just created is not yet synchronized into the database. Run the following command to generate a new migration that reflects the creation of the new model:

```
python manage.py makemigrations APPNAME
```

and

```
python manage.py migrate
```

After this, the new table exists in the database. Now, open the admin.py file of the blog application, import the Comment model, and add the following ModelAdmin class:

```
from .models import Post, Comment

@admin.register(Comment)
class CommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'email', 'post', 'created', 'active')
    list_filter = ('active', 'created', 'updated')
    search_fields = ('name', 'email', 'body')
```

---

> 2. Create a form to submit comments and validate the input data

Edit the forms.py file of your blog application and add the following lines:

```
from .models import Comment

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'body')
```

---

> 3. Add a view that processes the form and saves the new comment to the database

Edit the views.py file, add imports for the Comment model and the CommentForm form, and modify the post detail view to make it look like the following:

```
from .models import Post, Comment
from .forms import EmailPostForm, CommentForm

def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post,
                                   status='published',
                                   publish__year=year,
                                   publish__month=month,
                                   publish__day=day)

    # List of active comments for this post
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)

    new_comment = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # A comment was posted
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            # Create Comment object but don't save to database yet          
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            # Assign the current post to the comment
            new_comment.post = post
            # Save the comment to the database
            new_comment.save()
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()                   
    return render(request,
                  'blog/post/detail.html',
                  {'post': post,
                   'comments': comments,
                   'new_comment': new_comment,
                   'comment_form': comment_form})
```

---

> 4. Edit the post detail template to display the list of comments and the form to add a new comment

At this point we have created the functionality to manage comments for a post. Now, we will need to adapt our post/detail.html template to do the following things:
 - Display the list of comments
 - Display a form for users to add a new comment

Append the following lines to the post/detail.html template for the list of comments:

```
{% for comment in comments %}
  <div class="comment">
    <p class="info">
      Comment {{ forloop.counter }} by {{ comment.name }}
      {{ comment.created }}
    </p>
    {{ comment.body|linebreaks }}
  </div>
{% empty %}
  <p>There are no comments yet.</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Then, for the other point, add the following lines:

```
{% if new_comment %}
  <h2>Your comment has been added.</h2>
{% else %}
  <h2>Add a new comment</h2>
  <form action="." method="post">
    {{ comment_form.as_p }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Add comment"></p>
  </form>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help so far i can create posts with admin and persist on DB, but im unable to create and render from front..
i created posts/detail.html and add the first code from step 4 and the second code from step for on posts/feed html... i dont see the label to create and i dont see the comments, could you please update the last step ?

Comment: im not gettingany error messages, on my post(from front) i see only the button to add comment but no label.. and i created a list of comment for a post but i also unable to see it

Comment: im getting There are no comments yet. when i had created a post from admin also

Comment: also i canged to model on comment to ... 
post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=1, blank=True)
cause in the way that you mention i receive ERRORS:
comments.Comment.post: (fields.E302) Reverse accessor for 'Comment.post' clashes with field name 'Post.comments'.
        HINT: Rename field 'Post.comments', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'Comment.post'.
comments.Comment.post: (fields.E303) Reverse query name for 'Comment.post' clashes with field name 'Post.comments'.

Comment: What do you mean with «but no label»?

Comment: that i have the button to add a new comment ... but i dont have a label to put my comment

Comment: Please update your question with all the things you've done and explaining what is happening and what should happen. Or even better, create another question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60689503/django-cannot-create-or-render-comments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209652/discussion-between-guillermo-nahuel-varelli-and-tiago-martins-peres).